# How could I tell a give directory is git repo(bare or not bare) in Python

Tags: python, git

Is there any way to tell if a directory is a GIT repo in Python?

I am try to check if there's ".git" under that directory, but it doesn't work with bare repo.

Comment: What does "bare repo" mean" ? I think there is always a .git folder on repository folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [GitPython](https://pythonhosted.org/GitPython/0.3.1/tutorial.html):

```
from git import Repo, InvalidGitRepositoryError

try:
    Repo(path_to_repo)
    print 'is git repo'
except InvalidGitRepositoryError:
    print 'isn`t git repo'
```

Comment: +1  note that this just delegates to `git.repo.is_git_dir`, so it might be preferable to cut out the middleman and just use that.

Comment: @wim I think it doesn't work. First is_git_dir should be in git.repo.fun.is_git_dir. Second, if you give the root directory of a repo, it return "False", you have to give it as "<repo_dir>/.git" to make it return true.

Comment: @zymud Thanks for your answer, it works for Python2, but GitPython doesn't support Python3 yet. And the project is idled for a while. Now the maintainer comes back, hope we can see you release soon.

Comment: It does work, because that is what `Repo.__init__` uses.  But you are correct that it checks in both the cwd and ./.git.